# Boost.log synchronization problem

Tags: c++, logging, boost, synchronization

I trying to use Boost.log library from Andrey Semashev

I have some problem with multithreaded-logging with settings file.

Code of main program:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
using boost::shared_ptr;

// Here we define our application severity levels.
enum severity_level
{
    normal,
    notification,
    warning,
    error,
    critical
};

BOOST_LOG_DECLARE_GLOBAL_LOGGER(test_lg, src::severity_logger_mt<>)

void try_logging( std::string c )
{
    BOOST_LOG_SCOPED_THREAD_TAG("Tag", std::string, c.c_str());

    src::severity_logger_mt<>& lg = get_test_lg();
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, normal) << "This is a normal severity record";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, notification) << "This is a notification severity record";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, warning) << "This is a warning severity record";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, error) << "This is a error severity record";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, critical) << "This is a critical severity record";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        // Open the file
        std::ifstream settings("settings.txt");
        if (!settings.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "Could not open settings.txt file" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Read the settings and initialize logging library
        logging::init_from_stream(settings);

        shared_ptr< logging::attribute > attr(new attrs::local_clock);
        logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", attr);

        boost::thread_group g;
        for (char i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++)
            g.create_thread(boost::bind(&try_logging, std::string("aaa") + i));

        g.join_all();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "FAILURE: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Settings file:

```
[Core]

Filter="%Severity% >= 2"

[Sink:2]

Destination=TextFile
FileName=test.log
AutoFlush=true
Format="[%TimeStamp%] %Tag% %_%"
Asynchronous=1
Filter="%Tag% = aaab"

[Sink:3]
Filter="%Tag% = aaaa"
Asynchronous=1
Destination=TextFile
FileName=test.log
AutoFlush=true
Format="%Tag% %_%"
```

As you see, i setup filtering: i want to output just messages from aaab, aaaa threads.

But result file is very bad:

```
[2011-Jul-18 11:32:58.078192] aaab This aaaa This is a error severity [2011-Juaaaa This is a critical severity record
r severity record
[2011-Jul-18 11:32:58.437581] aaab This is a critical severity record
```

One message override other! As I understood - there's no synchronyzing between multiple threads.

If i remove filtering - result is all rigth.

How i can fix it? If it's possible - with config file, not code.

Thank you.